# STM32 Wakes up from standby mode immediately

Tags: stm32, rtc, sleep

I'm trying to get my board (STM32L072CZ) to enter the standby sleep mode, and it seems to be entering this mode, but it also immediately wakes up again. After searching the great webs the solution seems to be to clear the wake up flags at startup, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

What am I missing?

My code is as follows for what should be a 5 second sleep woken up by the RTC.

```C
    /* Clear the WU FLAG */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

     /* clear the RTC Wake UP (WU) flag */
    __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_CLEAR_FLAG(&hrtc, RTC_FLAG_WUTF);

    // If starting from standby mode
    if (__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
      {
          __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);  // clear the flag
          printf("Wakeup time! \r\n");

          HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&hrtc);
      }

    if (HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, (0x2710), RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();
```

Comment: What environment are you using? What is the configuration of the peripherals? Post that part, too. For example, if you are using an OS, the tick timer will wake it up. The same goes for the other peripheral interrupts.

Comment: Low-power modes may have several issues, and I'm not going to investigate your particular code - and in no way code using Cube/HAL or any other "library".

However, you may want to read [this post](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-embedded-software/how-to-enter-standby-or-shutdown-mode-on-stm32/td-p/145849) for a couple of potential issues.